# Google Fit app not working when compiled from other PC

Tags: android, google-fit

I have used **Google Fit Sensor API** following the documentation. It worked. Then I copied my android project and compiled from another PC. But this time it's not working. After selecting my account for auth, I get **RESULT_CANCELED** in **onActivityResult** method.

Google Play services and Google Repository SDK tools are installed and updated in that other PC. Do I have to create a new Client ID to use from other PC?

Comment: Probably because the `SHA` you have added on Google API console has Changed ..Add the new `SHA` and it will work ..

Comment: @ADM It worked when I compiled from my PC again. If `SHA` was changed on Google API console, should it work from my PC later?

Comment: Yeah it will work because you have already added Sha for this pc .

Comment: @ADM Thanks! It worked after adding a new credential with other PC's `SHA`.